# TFS Build machine cannot find v14.0 platform toolset

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

Starting situation:
TFS 2013 build machine (agent), with VS2013 installed. This successfully builds my solution.

Afterwards:
I have upgraded projects within my solution to VS2015 project, ie using v14.0 platform toolset. The solution builds locally using VS2015 with no problems.
I have installed VS2015 on the build agent.

The build agent now cannot build the solution, saying that

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets (64): The build tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 build tools, please install v140 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".
```

I have tried customizing the build template, setting `ToolVersion` in MSBuild to `"14.0"`, with the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to uninstall VS2013 on the build agent right now - it's taking ages though. However, even if that helps, it would not be an ultimate solution to the problem - I need that agent to build VS2013 projects as well.

Comment: Ok, after uninstalling VS2013, I run into a different issue:
The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
I have managed to resolve that by manually setting the MSBuild arguments in the build configuration to " /p:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140" ". I believe this would have also helped while I've had VS2013 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing build definition and manually supplying this in `MSBuild arguments` helps:

```
/p:VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140"
```

After this, the build runs ok.

While having this as an answer for now, I do not like this solution. Why should I be supplying an absolute path in the build definition?